# Which one is faster? Onload() function or putting your code directly inside the <script>?

Tags: javascript, html

What is the difference between calling your javascript action through onload() function and putting them directly inside the `<script>`?

1. **I would like to see if there is a difference in terms of the speed(or any) when the code runs.**
2. **Which one executes first?**
3. **Which one is faster?**(It doesn't always mean that if the code executes first, it runs faster)

Comment: The plain `<script>` code will run *immediately*, the other code will run on *document load*, which is (sometimes) later.

Comment: It should also be noted that immediately means that not all the elements may be loaded when it runs.  Depending on where you put the <script> tag.

Comment: *Some* code in the global scope runs *considerably* slower than if it were inside a function - so, while onload will start later, it could run faster - of course, this is very dependant on the code itself - so, not really worth mentioning

Comment: @JaromandaX What sort of code exhibits that behavior, can you explain a bit? I've never heard about that.

Comment: Aaargh - I knew someone would ask @CertainPerformance - it's been a while since I've come across it - I'll see wht I can find

Comment: @CertainPerformance - https://pastebin.com/cmEKPpSp put that in your browser console - in firefox the difference is dramatic (4000ms, 2000ms, 9ms) - in chrome, not so much (26ms, 24ms, 12ms)

Comment: @JaromandaX Interesting, thanks. Depends on the engine, I initially thought that maybe the interpreter has to go through the big list of global properties until it finds the right one that's being referred to, but that sounds odd, that sort of thing *sounds* like it should be `O(1)`, and also sounds like something that would be done *once* while translating to bytecode, and not on every iteration.

Comment: @JaromandaX These FF results seem really specific to the console environment. When [ran as part of a document parsing](https://jsfiddle.net/ke04s89r/), even in the global scope, results are more like the ones of chrome (avg 20 20 10 for me). They probably don't run the optimizer for debugger code. Still good to know, but very little to do with the question here ;)

Comment: True. But I've seen code in the past behave that way though not as dramatically. Engines get better over time

Comment: Yes trying to know how an engine will optimize code is a lost cause... The time you'll find for one engine, it will have changed in the next version ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code inside a `<script>` block is executed immediately when it's encountered during page parse. 
The `onload` event handler will execute code after the page (and its assets) have loaded.

If you want a script to run as quickly as possible, consider declaring a script block in your pages `<head/>` block, before any `<link/>` elements. Note that in doing this, your script won't be able to rely on third party plugins or libraries.